# What are the internals of Pythons str.join()? (Hiding passwords from output)

Tags: python

I just stumbled upon an interesting(?) way to hide passwords (and other personal data) from general output from screen to logfiles.

In his book [How to make mistakes in Python](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/files/how-to-make-mistakes-in-python.pdf) Mike Pirnat suggests to implement a class for sensitive strings and to overload its `__str__`- and `__repr__`-methods.

I experimented with that and got this:

```py
class secret(str):

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.string = s

    def __repr__(self):
        return "'" + "R"*len(self.string) + "'"

    def __str__(self):
        return "S" * len(self.string)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return str.__add__(self.__str__(), other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return str.__add__(other, self.__str__())

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        return ("X"*len(self.string))[i:j]
```

(I'm aware that using `len` provides information about the content to hide. It's just for testing.)

It works fine in this cases:

```py
pwd = secret("nothidden")

print("The passwort is " + pwd)                  # The passwort is SSSSSSSSS
print(pwd + " is the passwort.")                 # SSSSSSSSS is the password.

print("The passwort is {}.".format(pwd))         # The password is SSSSSSSSS.
print(["The", "passwort", "is", pwd])            # ['The', 'password', 'is', 'RRRRRRRRR']
print(pwd[:])                                    # XXXXXXXXX
```

However this does not work:

```py
print(" ".join(["The", "password", "is", pwd]))  # The password is nothidden
```

So, how does str.join() work internally? Which method would I have to overload to obscure the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are inheriting from `str`, which likely implements `__new__` which means that even though you avoided calling the parent constructor in your class, the underlying C object is still initialized with it.

Now `join` is probably checking if it has a `str` subclass and, being implemented in C, it access directly the underlying C structure, or uses an other `str`-related function which bypasses `__str__` and `__repr__` (think about it: if the value is a string or a string subclass, why would the code call `__str__` or `__repr__` to obtain its value? It just accesses the underlying character array in some way!)

To fix this: do **not** inherit from `str`! Unfortunately this means you will not be able to use that object exactly like a string in some situations, but that's pretty much inevitable.

---

An alternative that may work is to implement `__new__` and feed a different value to `str`'s `__new__` method:

```
class secret(str):
    def __new__(cls, initializer):
        return super(secret, cls).__new__(cls, 'X'*len(initializer))
    def __init__(self, initializer):
        self.text = initializer
    def __repr__(self):
        return "'{}'".format("R"*len(self))
    def __str__(self):
        return "S"*len(self)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self) + other
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + str(self)
```

Which results in:

```
In [19]: pwd = secret('nothidden')

In [20]: print("The passwort is " + pwd)                  # The passwort is SSSSSSSSS
    ...: print(pwd + " is the passwort.")                 # SSSSSSSSS is the password.
    ...: 
    ...: print("The passwort is {}.".format(pwd))         # The password is SSSSSSSSS.
    ...: print(["The", "passwort", "is", pwd])            # ['The', 'password', 'is', 'RRRRRRRRR']
    ...: print(pwd[:])
The passwort is SSSSSSSSS
SSSSSSSSS is the passwort.
The passwort is SSSSSSSSS.
['The', 'passwort', 'is', 'RRRRRRRRR']
XXXXXXXXX

In [21]: print(" ".join(["The", "password", "is", pwd]))
The password is XXXXXXXXX
```

However I fail to really see how this is useful. I mean: the purpose of this class is to avoid programming errors that end up display sensitive information? But then having an exception being triggered is better so that you can identify the bugs! For that it's probably best to `raise NotImplementedError` inside `__str__` and `__repr__` instead of silently provided a useless value... sure you don't leak the secret but finding bugs becomes really hard.

Comment: This sort of works. `print(" ".join(["The", "password", "is", pwd]))` will produce a traceback, but wrapping `pwd` in `str()` will produce the desired output. Of course, that would fix the original version as well. I guess this is a little safer, producing a traceback instead of printing the hidden string.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've provided an implementation that works as you expected, and added a note about why this isn't really terribly useful... if you don't want something displayed I'd simply *not* implement some of those methods or raise an exception when they are called.

Comment: It's not as much about programming *errors* but about convenience when, say, logging a REST query or similar, so you don't have to obscure it yourself everytime.
And for the most important part it was curiosity.
But you're probably right, that there are better ways to avoid printing sensible data.